# How do I add an Anti Forgery Token and a CDN

Tags: sitecore-forms, cdn

Using Sitecore 9.3...

We are using a CDN to fully cache the entire HTML of the page. This is causing a problem with Experience Forms and the AntiForgeryToken. The value of the token gets cached. Then I submit the form and it fails antiforgery validation. I am pursuing two avenues of resolution, so far I have not been able to resolve either, but still working:

1. Ajax in the value of the token - Microsoft's method for generating this token is public.

This works locally, have yet to test on the CDN

2. Replace the Experience Forms controller - Create a custom controller thats a copy of Sitecore's but remove the request validation token check.

How would I replace this? Can I override the route: /formbuilder by setting it last, ensuring it used my route?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm looking at the same issue, and was considering AJAXing in the value of the token too.

Comment: I replaced the controller with a custom controller and turned off the anti-forgery token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can potentially replace controller used by Sitecore Experience Forms by adding a patch file which changes `implementationType` for `serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc"` service.

Original service is registered in `App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms\Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.config` config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery">
    <services>
      <register
        ​serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc"
        ​​implementationType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure if that's the best idea though. It's there for security reason

Comment: You mean the antiforgery token?

Comment: Yes, antiforgery token. If you're ok that anyone can call your controller without really filling form on your website, then removing `[ValidateFormRequest]` attribute in your custom `FormBuilderController` should do the trick for you